# Determine what PHP is doing during OOM kill?

Tags: php, linux, out-of-memory

asterisk keeps crashing because of OOM(out of memory).
When i check my syslog it says

> php invoked oom-killer:
>   gfp_mask=0x27000c0(GFP_KERNEL_ACCOUNT|__GFP_NOTRACK), order=2,
>   oom_score_adj=0.

I dont have any cronjobs running,

Is there any way to find out what is php doing when it happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [register_shutdown_function()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to register a callback that can check [error_get_last()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php).

Comment: i have increase my memory :D